# Java Script, ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need some help,

```
<asp:Image ID="imgCaptcha" CssClass="Captcha" ImageUrl="/ashx/captcha.ashx" runat="server" />
<button id="refreshcaptcha" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" aria-label="Refresh"> <i class="fa fa-lg fa-refresh"></i> </button>
```

JScript

```
$("#refreshcaptcha").click(function (parameters) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "contactus.aspx/RefreshCaptcha",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var src = $('#<%= imgCaptcha.ClientID %>').attr("src");
            if (endsWith(src, "ashx")) {
                $('#<%= imgCaptcha.ClientID %>').attr("src", src + "?" + Math.random());
            } else {
                src = src.substring(0, src.indexOf('?'));
                $('#<%= imgCaptcha.ClientID %>').attr("src", src + "?" + Math.random());
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {}
    });
    function endsWith(str, suffix) {
        return str.indexOf(suffix, str.length - suffix.length) !== -1;
    }
});
```

Above JS is on .aspx page and it's working OK,
How can I move this block of JS code into a separate but linked .js file?
What do I need to change into the JS code?

Comment: Why are you making a POST request and claiming that the content-type o the data you are sending is JSON when you have no `data:` attribute in the config object?

Comment: depends of the structure you're using but in general, just create a new js file then use it as reference like `<script src="path/yourjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` in your page

Comment: @Dumisani — Won't work. `$('#<%= imgCaptcha.ClientID %>')` would break in a static js file.

Comment: @ElmerDantas — Won't work. `$('#<%= imgCaptcha.ClientID %>')` would break in a static js file.

Comment: Please don't use comments to give answers. Give real answers if you are going to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the ClientIDMode attribute to your `<asp:Image>` and set it to Static then use that id to access it in your javascript file.

For example:

```
<asp:Image ID="imgCaptcha" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="Captcha" ImageUrl="/ashx/captcha.ashx" runat="server" />

$('#imgCaptcha').attr("src", src + "?" + Math.random());
```

Comment: "Add the ClientIDMode attrivute to your and set it to" — This is riddled with so many grammar and spelling mistakes that I don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: An explanation as to what setting that "attrivute" (attribute?) to Static actually means would probably make this a better answer too.

Comment: It would make the control's id on the DOM the same as the server side's control Id

Comment: louk thanks a lot for your help  "ClientIDMode attribute" was missing :)

Answer (score -1):

Think of how you would do this in a NON ASP environment. What 'changes' do you have to make there? ASP is no different in that respect. Include the JS file in the ASP page. Generally this is done with some sort of standard header for your pages.

Comment: The JS includes ID values which are generated by ASP.NET. Simply writing the code as if ASP.NET didn't exist wouldn't fill in those gaps.